# If $[M,M] \cong [L,L]$ and $\dfrac{M}{[M,M]} \cong \dfrac{L}{[L,L]}$ then $M \not \simeq L$

Tags: solution-verification, lie-algebras

**Question:**

Given two finite dimensional complex Lie algebras $M$ and $L$ whose derived subalgebras $[M,M] \cong [L,L]$ and whose quotients $\dfrac{M}{[M,M]} \cong \dfrac{L}{[L,L]}$, is it necessarily true that the Lie algebras $M$ and $L$ are isomorphic?

I believe that the answer to this question is no, however I am unsure how to prove it, I have been trying to construct a counter example using non-simple $3$ dimensional Lie algebras, here is the progress I have made so far:

**My Attempt:**

If $[M,M]$ and $[L,L]$ are 1-dimensional, then they are abelian and are isomorphic. In this case the quotients $\dfrac{M}{[M,M]}$ and $\dfrac{L}{[L,L]}$ are both abelian by the induced Lie bracket on the quotients. Since there are only two $2$ dimensional lie algebras up to isomorphism, these quotient Lie algebras must also be isomorphic.

Now I try to construct such Lie algebras which are not isomorphic. Let $\{x,y,z\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$ be bases for $M$ and $L$ respectively and define the Lie brackets on $M$ and $L$ via the following:
$[x,y] = z, [x,z]=0, [y,z]=0$ and $[a,b] = k_1a+k_2b,[a,c]=[b,c]=0 $ where $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

I think that this means $M$ and $L$ are not isomorphic as even though all of the required conditions are satisfied, $M$ and $L$ have different structure constants so they cannot be isomorphic.

**Question:**

Does this actually show that these lie algebras are non-isomorphic? I am concerned that there could perhaps be a change of basis which I could perform which allows the structure constants to actually be equal.

Comment: I don't understand "Since there are only two 2 dimensional ... quotient Lie algebras must also be isomorphic". I thought the quotients are isomorphic *by assumption*, and you inquire whether the entire LAs are isomorphic? Also, the dimension of the derived subalgebra says nothing about the dim of the quotient ... Is this maybe supposed to be the case where both the derived algebra and the quotient are one-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, the intention is for the quotients to be isomorphic by assumption, though I wanted to be sure that letting the derived subalgebras being 1 dimensional wouldn't lead to an immediate contradiction. I was also unaware that knowing the dimension of derived subalgebras tells us nothing about the quotient

Comment: The first Lie algebra $M$ is the Heisenberg Lie algebra, which is nilpotent. The second one is not nilpotent by Engel, as soon as $k_1,k_2$ are not both zero. Your first sentence in the attempt is not correct. The quotients need not be both abelian in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\lambda\in \Bbb C^{\times}$ let $\mathfrak{r}_3(\lambda)$ denote the $3$-dimensional solvable Lie algebra with basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and defining brackets
$$
[e_1,e_2]=e_2,\; [e_1,e_3]=\lambda e_3.
$$
We have $\mathfrak{r}_3(\lambda)\cong \mathfrak{r}_3(\mu)$ if and only if $\lambda=\mu$ or $\lambda=\mu^{-1}$. So let
$$
M=\mathfrak{r}_3(\lambda),\; N=\mathfrak{r}_3(\mu)
$$
be non-isomorphic. We have $[M,M]=\langle e_2,e_3\rangle \cong \Bbb C^2$ and the same for $[N,N]\cong \Bbb C^2$. Also the quotients are both $1$-dimensional abelian Lie algebras, hence isomorphic. But $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic, e.g., for $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=2$.